# What can we say about the kernel of a linear functional on an infinite dimensional Banach space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, and let $\lambda \in X^*$. since the rank-nullity theorem can not be used in the infinite dimensional case, what can we say about the dimension of the kernel of $\lambda$ ? Can we say that kernel of $\lambda$ has finite codimension?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\lambda \ne 0$, its kernel has codimension $1$.  Namely, if $u\in X$ with $\lambda(u) \ne 0$, every member of $X$ can be written as
$$ x = \dfrac{\lambda(x)}{\lambda(u)} u + w$$
where $\lambda(w) = 0$.